# Why Does MongoDb Align Collection keys alphabetically after Update

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

i have seen that whenever we update any values into mongo collection. After update it realign the keys alphabetically. Suppose if the current schema is

```
  _id:"Objectid(blah blah)"
     id: "1", 
fullname: "user",
 username: "username", 
password: "password",
```

After update it become

```
 _id:"Objectid(blah blah)"
    fullname:"user"
    id:"1"
    password:"password"
    username:"user"
```

I know there is no problem with this. and this wont affect anything as in array data remains correspondent to value. but i am just curious to know why this happens.

Edit:

This is the update function code in mongoshell. But this didn't helped me though

```
function (query, obj, upsert, multi) {
    assert(query, "need a query");
    assert(obj, "need an object");
    var firstKey = null;
    for (var k in obj) {
        firstKey = k;
        break;
    }
    if (firstKey != null && firstKey[0] == "$") {
        this._validateObject(obj);
    } else {
        this._validateForStorage(obj);
    }
    if (typeof upsert === "object") {
        assert(multi === undefined, "Fourth argument must be empty when specifying upsert and multi with an object.");
        opts = upsert;
        multi = opts.multi;
        upsert = opts.upsert;
    }
    this._db._initExtraInfo();
    this._mongo.update(this._fullName, query, obj, upsert ? true : false, multi ? true : false);
    this._db._getExtraInfo("Updated");
}
```

Comment: Without having looked at the source, I assume that they are using a binary tree to store the key/value pairs.

Comment: are you using driver or do you use the pure mongo shell?

Comment: @eran For both driver and mongo shell . it happens.

Comment: can you paste your update command?

Comment: Which field(s) are you updating?   And is this a multi update?  Does it grow the document size?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky No. its not a multiupdate. neither its increasing document size. its just incrementing a login attempt field in document by 1.

Comment: so your own answer (and experiments) show that this does NOT happen if it's "just incrementing" - that's why I asked if the size of the document is changing.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: what do you mean?  If you do an update with $inc of an existing field, the document stays the same - I tested it myself.  So what does not seem to be correct in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc says they they are reordered in the doc size increases over the allocated size, however, it seems that they are reordered whenever the document size changes (if this is the same size it does not change).

For example, here the first command does not change, but the second one does.

```
> db.t3.insert({_id : 1234',id:'xxx',
fullname:'use1',password:'password','username':'user'})
> db.t3.update({'_id':'1234'},{$set : {fullname:'use1'}})
> db.t3.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "id" : "xxx",
    "fullname" : "use1",
    "password" : "password",
    "username" : "user"
}
> db.t3.update({'_id':'1234'},{$set : {fullname:'use11'}})
> db.t3.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "fullname" : "use11",
    "id" : "xxx",
    "password" : "password",
    "username" : "user"
}
```

Look here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592

Comment: This seems good. But in my case even if document size dont change it still reorder the documents.
original update command is db.users.update({"username":"user"},$set : {login-attempt:'1'}})
As you can see i am not increasing size of document. just incrementing the login attempt value every time.
by the way one main point i am using http://genghisapp.com to monitor mongodb .if i edit from that app. there is no reordering of documents in collection